# Horizontal and vertical menu

Tags: html, css

So I need to create vertical and horizontal menu. The horizontal one has to be done using "display: inline", but I don't really know how to do It. Also I would like to add some css editing like using hover to change button background so It will look like It's animated but I can't use js, only pure css. Add random sites to menu buttons[image]

Answer (score 2):

use flexbox for your styling in horizontal and vertical:
for instance :

```css
//for horizontal
div{
 display: flex;
}

//for vertical
div{
 display : flex;
 flex-direction : column;
}
```

Comment: Hi, i just wanted to point out that the snippet here isn't runnable here since it only contains CSS code. If you are using this snippet feature, you can add HTML codes as well to make the code runnable and enable us to test the code live. Or you can use code fences instead if you prefer to have a non executable CSS only code. This isn't necessary at all but i just wanted to say that it isn't really useful to create a non-executable snippet. Anyways have a great day :D

Answer (score 0):

Use display flex to do that. You'll get very useful guides here https://flexbox.malven.co/.

For css You can easily do that using `:hover` for example :

```
.item:hover {
    background-color: red;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}
```

You can play with different transition types to find one matching your requirements.